# How to display objectId ref data with $lookup and aggregate in mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework, backend, lookup

I have the following Schema and route. Although am able to display the data, clientdetails which is an objectId doesn't display its entire code, it only displays the objectId.My problem is that am not able to fully display entire clientdetails data.I would like to query the combined three collections with clientdetails.fullName. Moreover in the frontend i get empty arrays for both saleslocationInfo and billsInfo.

ClientSchema.Js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    fullName:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    gender:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    nationality:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    address:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema)
```

BillSchema.Js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const billSchema = new Schema({
      paymentReferenceCode:{
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      paymentType:{
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
     AmountPaid:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
     Total:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },
    clientdetails: {
        ref: 'Client',
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    
}, { timestamps: true })


module.exports = mongoose.model('Bill',billSchema);
```

SaleslocationSchema.Js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SalesLocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    country:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    city:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    clientdetails: {
        ref: 'Client',
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Saleslocation', SalesLocationSchema)
```

StaffSchema.Js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StaffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    staffName:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    staffDepartment:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    clientdetails: {
        ref: 'Client',
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
 });


 module.exports = mongoose.model('Staff', StaffSchema)
```

SalesRoute.js

```
router.get('/query', (req, res, next) => {
staffs.aggregate([
     { "$lookup": {     
             "from": "saleslocations",     
             "localField": "clientdetails",     
             "foreignField": "clientdetails",     
             "as": "saleslocationsInfo"   
     }}, 
     { "$lookup": {     
       "from": "bills",     
       "localField": "clientdetails",     
       "foreignField": "clientdetails",     
       "as": "billsInfo"   
}}, 
    
 ],
 (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
      console.error(err);
  }
  res.json(data);
 }
 )}
)
```

```
  Expected Output

        [
        {
            "_id": "",
            "staffName": "",
            "staffDepartment": "",
            "clientdetails": [{
                "fullName":"",
                "gender":"",
                "nationality":"",
                "address":"",
                "date":""
        }],
        "saleslocationInfo": [{
                 "country":"",
                  "city":"",
                  "clientdetails": [{
                    "fullName":"",
                    "gender":"",
                    "nationality":"",
                    "address":"",
                    "date":""
        }]}],
              "billsInfo":[{
                   "paymentReferenceCode":"",
                   "paymentType":"",
                   "AmountPaid":"",
                   "Total":"",
                    "clientdetails": [{
                        "fullName":"",
                        "gender":"",
                        "nationality":"",
                        "address":"",
                        "date":""
                        }]   
        }]}]
```

I would like to retrieve the entire clientdetails data as well. Currently am only getting objectID(633b2b8d3631a23bf5da9a9d). Moreover, i would like to solve the problem of empty arrays in the frontend for staff, saleslocationInfo and billsInfo. Thank you

Comment: Try using `"foreignField": "_id"`

Comment: @Joe thanks, when i change to _id in the foreignfield i get  now empty array like this. saleslocationInfo[ ]

Comment: Ah, I misread your explanation.  Starting from staffs you are fetching documents from saleslocations and bills based on matching clientdetails, which is an ObjectID in all 3 collections.  If you want to expand those into full documents, you'll need to do a further lookup from the clients collection to get that data.